# "Undo" on a single object

Tags: modeling

Is it possible in blender to undo the changes done onto a single object. Say I have a model, and I made a few changes. At a later point I realize I want to make two variations form a similar base. Could I then duplicate the object as I have it now, then select the original, and undo all the changes on the original object so I can create a second version from a common point?

Comment: im afraid thats not possible but u could just make a duplicate backup `Shift`+`D` and make it invisible `H`until u need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then yes it is possible if you have enough undo steps to get back to the "original object".    Edit > Preferences > System > Memory and Limits > Undo Steps.

One method would be: In Edit or Object mode > Select your modified model > Ctrl C (to copy it to your clipboard) > Make all the undo steps necessary to get back to your original object > The in **Object mode** > Ctrl V (to paste back the modified object into your scene).

Another method would be to copy the modified model (Ctrl C) > Open an second instance of Blender and paste (Ctrl V) it in there for safe keeping. Then, when you are done with all the undo steps, you can go to your second Blender instance and copy and paste it back into the original instance of Blender.